# How to access variable from other view page on yii2?

Tags: yii2

How to access variable ($imodel->grade) in tampil.php page and then subsequently put on the page view.php with post method. Sorry for the question, i'm newbie in OOP, MVC and Yii. Please help me guys

Here is The code of actionIndex:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $imodel = new Grade();

  if($imodel->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
  { 
    $imodel->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
    $imodel->grade;

       $query = Nilaiharian::find(); //select nis, $grade, nama from nilaiharian
       $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider(['query' => $query,]);

       return $this->render('tampil', ['imodel' => $imodel, 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,] );
  } 
  else
  {
    return $this->render('index', ['imodel' => $imodel, ] );   
  }
}
```

And this is a code of tampil.php

```
<?php 

    echo "Nilai untuk ".$imodel->grade; 
    echo "<br>";
    echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'nis',
        $imodel->grade,
        'nama',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                    'template'  => '{view}{update}{delete}',
                    'buttons' => [
                            'view' => function ($url, $model) {
                                    return Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>', 
                                      $url, ['title' => Yii::t('app', 'Show'), 'name'=>'view', 'value'=>'view', 'style' => 'margin-right:10px;', ]);
                            },
                            'update' => function ($url, $model) {
                                    return Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>', 
                                      $url, ['title' => Yii::t('app', 'Edit'), 'name'=>'update', 'style' => 'margin-right:10px;', ]);
                            },
                            'delete' => function ($url, $model) {
                                    return Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>', 
                                      $url, ['title' => Yii::t('app', 'Delete'), 'name'=>'delete', 'data-confirm'=>'Are you sure you want to delete this record?']);
                            }
                    ]
            ],
     ], 

     ]); 
?>
```

Comment: simply use `grade` instead of `$imodel->grade`. if `grade` in current model. No need to post data.

Comment: I write the code like this but not working.

Here is The code of actionIndex:
http://pastebin.com/T5Bmzxer

And this is the code of index.php:
http://pastebin.com/eruYvVqY

And this is the code of tampil.php:
http://pastebin.com/WC6ubHXr

And this is view.php code:
http://pastebin.com/bC3gDb4U

Comment: You want to display `grade` in `GridView`. Right?

Comment: Yes,, but i want to display the data from dropdownlist that I write in tampil.php. For more details I want to send my applications + SQL to your email, if you're willing

Comment: hey try this link http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#sharing-data-among-views